# Subdomain rewirte problem

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I trying to rewrite subdomain. 
For example test.mydomain.com to mydomain.com/test.php
I have create a domain *.mydomain.com. 
Now I want it to send data to mydomain.com/test.php when someone visits test.mydomain. com
It will send "test" as a data.

I tried this but its not working

```
RewriteEngine on    
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.mydomain.com [NC]    
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST) !^www\.   
RewriteRule /test.php?$1 [L]
```

Any solution? 
What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try write this

```
RewriteRule (.+) /test.php?$1 [L]
```

Instead of this

```
RewriteRule /test.php?$1 [L]
```

Also you can see some [basic help](http://www.reconn.us/content/view/46/67/)